# What's an example of a theorem with multiple ways to prove it?

Tags: proof-writing, big-list

Please give a simple example that incorporates basic math, like basic arithmetic. Please include the theorem and the multiple proofs (can just mention them, or include the entire proofs).

Comment: [The Pythaorean theorem has hundreds.](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/)

Comment: For instance https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/ where it in particular says "W. Dunham [Mathematical Universe] cites a book The Pythagorean Proposition by an early 20th century professor Elisha Scott Loomis. The book is a collection of 367 proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem". Most theorems have more than one proof.

Comment: Alright, you guys are too good. There was no tag for "newbie". Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for the downvote. I need to do more googling before asking.

Comment: Re: pythagorean theorem having that many proofs, that's truly amazing. Math seems way more nuanced and complex than I could imagine.

Comment: By the way, one of these proofs is by an American president (Garfield). Another theorem which is often cited as having a huge amount of proofs is Gauss' quadratic reciprocity, but it is not easy (its formulation is pretty elementary, but its proofs are far from trivial).

Comment: @imagineerThat: You could also just take a look around Math.SE. The fact that just-about every question here has multiple answers demonstrates that proofs of any given result are *far* from unique.

Comment: @imagineerThat I posted a solution to a problem here and had other people answer the same question using another technique at the same time. It's actually rather rare that there is only one way to prove something.

Comment: There are some questions listed under Related that have addressed this problem before.See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401493/theorems-with-many-distinct-proofs

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Oops! And thanks, good source!

Comment: The important theorems usually can be proven in several ways. I do not know the "hundreds of proofs" of the Pythagorean theorem, but I guess many of them have a very similar approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one.  Choose $n+1$ integers between $1$ and $2n$, inclusive.  Prove that one of your choices must divide another.

One proof uses induction on $n$.  Another completely different proof uses the pigeonhole principle.